# soloxbit.com genuine or fake crypto exchange?

Tags: exchanges

I am new in crypto. I know something about cryto currency and its working. Today some one suggested me soloxbit global  exchange is it a genuine crypto exchange or  not?
not enough material is available. is any one using it?

Comment: Claims "Founded in 2018" but soloxbit.com created only last month. Domain registrar in Russia. No office location. No company registration details. No ownership details, Website copies mexc.com.

Answer (score 0):

I have an account there and I deposited money and traded. Now I am trying to withdraw my money, and they want me to add 0.1btc so I can withdraw my money. I have 1200usdt there. I think they are scammers, and not really an exchange.