# Is www.soloxbit.com a legitimate exchange?

Tags: cryptography

help is needed urgently.

I have been invited to use a crypto exchange called **[www.soloxbit.com](http://www.soloxbit.com)** by a telegram group. I signed up as there was a 50% bonus on my first deposit using their referral.

My money is now stuck in the exchange as a verification deposit of 0.02BTC is required to get a "USER" status in order to withdraw.

Can anyone here please tell me if the exchange is legit and if I should make the verification deposit just to take my money out?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You got yourself scammed. It's gone. Whatever you do, do NOT send any more as that will immediately be gone as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell if a cryptocurrency exchange or trading platform is trustworthy?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/98743/how-to-tell-if-a-cryptocurrency-exchange-or-trading-platform-is-trustworthy). The same question about soloxbit was asked a few hours ago: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/114925/13866